# Redirecting with mod_rewrite and mod_geoip only if user asks for the root of the domain and are from a particular country

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need a rule and condition to handle this scenario:

User from US visits www.domain.com, domain.com, www.domain.com/ or domain.com/ this should be redirected to www.domain.com/usvisitor/

However, if a user from the US visits www.domain.com/anydirectory it will let them straight through without a redirection occurring.

eg.

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /

GeoIPEnable On  
GeoIPDBFile /var/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat  

RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^US$  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [L]  
RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.domain.com/usvisitor$1 [L]
```

I know the RewriteConditons and rules are wrong - just can't get my head around it!

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record got it solved:

```
RewriteEngine On  

GeoIPEnable On  
GeoIPDBFile /var/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat  
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^US$  
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain.com/usvisitor/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Simple really - doh!